# Problem retrieving data: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * From tblUserInfo WHERE Username='" & Trim(frmdashboard.ToolStripLabel4.Text) & "'", con)     

Dim table As New DataTable()
Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

sqlAdapter.Fill(table)

Me.UserTypeTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(10).ToString()
Me.UsernameTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(9).ToString()
Me.Email_AddressTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(12).ToString()
Me.PositionTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()

Me.NameTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
Me.AddressTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
Me.Date_of_BirthDateTimePicker.Value = table.Rows(0)(4).ToString()
Me.AgeTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(5).ToString()
Me.SexComboBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(6).ToString()
Me.Telephone_NumberTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(7).ToString()
Me.Mobile_NumberTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(8).ToString()

Me.Security_Question_1TextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(13).ToString()
Me.Security_Question_2TextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(15).ToString()

Dim img() As Byte

img = table.Rows(0)(17)

Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)

Me.PicturePictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

This should retrieve the data of a specific person. The error I get is

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0

Comment: The error means that your SQL statement returned no rows. That means that either your SQL is wrong or your data isn't what you expect.

Comment: The `Fill` method returns the number of rows that were retrieved so you can/should always test that to know whether you got any data or not.  Also, don't keep using `table.Rows(0)` over and over.  Assign it to a variable and then use that.  Finally, it doesn;t look like you should be using a data adapter at all.  If you're just assigning values from one record then probably use a data reader.

Comment: as a side note.. use parameterised queries.. something about sql injection and all that guff!

Comment: Previously this code works but after i finish other form when i test again the system that's when I get this error, i will retry to recode it

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figure out why all of a sudden this code gets in error, the reason is because of the previous form, the system cannot found any rows because the form is closed

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that your query will return at least one record which might/might not be true all times. You should first check if your tables has at least one row as below:

```
if ( table.Rows != null && tables.Rows.Count > 0)
{

    Dim img() As Byte;

    img = table.Rows(0)(17)

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)

    Me.PicturePictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
}
```